# How to link picture in article

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How can i link pictures inside article to current article?

Joomla V2.5

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin login with your administration username/password.

then go to article manager. select article which you need insert an image,

click on image btn on editor past your image link on a image url. click on save btn it will include image in article.